# need a unix script that will validate that there is no space in a given path

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

My requirement is simple
I have a file with a list of paths provided in a line.

Eg:

```
/etc/home
/var/www/
```

I need a command to validate that there are no space characters in between the path like: `/var/ www/`

How can I achieve this validation?

Comment: `grep ' ' file`?

Comment: Is this *really* a better task than making sure that paths with spaces in them work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help. It uses the Internal Field Separator.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ ! $1 ]; then
        echo Filename parameter expected
        exit
fi
export IFS=$'\n'
for i in `cat $1`
do
if [ `echo $i | grep ' ' ` ]; then
        echo Spaces found in [$i]
else
        echo No spaces found in [$i]
fi
done
```

Comment: works like a charm. Thanks. Can you please tell me more about IFS?

Comment: Well you surely can look up for Unix IFS over internet. By default "space" is used as a field separator. And we tweaked it to use "new line", "eol" or "\n" to be used as field separator. So it will treat the string as one field till it finds "eol" character.